# Jekyll overwrites output folder and CSS generated by Compass

Tags: jekyll, compass-sass

I am trying to use Jekyll together with Compass.
On one command line I'm running `jekyll --auto` and in another one `compass watch`.
The SASS files are located in `/stylesheets` and are compiled into `/_site/stylesheets`.
Jekyll is configured to ignore `/stylesheets`.

Compiling the stylesheets works fine in the beginning, but everytime I change something that makes Jekyll regenerate the site, it overwrites the whole `/_site` folder and `/_site/stylesheets` is gone. Compass doesn't regenerate it since the source SASS files haven't changed.

Is there another way to use Jekyll together with Compass?
Can I configure Jekyll to not overwrite the complete output folder but just the files that changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using Jekyll & Compass for my github page. here: https://github.com/ardianzzz/ardianzzz.github.com

Simple,
I just put the generated css folder in the root folder. Jekyll will generate the file inside `_site` folder.

As you can see in my repository.

Just call the CSS with the following code

```
<link href = "/css/screen.css" ...
```

bad english, sorry. :)

Comment: Great! Do you have an answer for my question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ardianzzz! Yes, putting the stylesheet folder into the root folder would definitely be one option.

Comment: This is what I went with in the end. Have my SASS files in /stylesheets and let Jekyll ignore that folder. Comfigure Compass to compile into /css and that folder will automatically be pulled in to /_site.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Jekyll, when run, scraps all the contents of the _site directory. The way I got around this was to use rake for deployment, and then have the following in my rakefile:

```
task :generate => :clear do
    sh 'jekyll'
    sh 'compass compile'
end
```

I then just run:

```
$ rake generate
```

Which populates the jekyll directory, and then puts the compass files over.

A neater solution might be to make your compass -watch process (assuming that is what you are running) compile the compass to projectdir/css. When you then run jekyll it will just pull that css directory directly into _site/css and you're done, no problems (see below for dir structure).

```
projectdir/
    css/
    stylesheets/
```

If you put anything in _site/css and then run jekyll after it will be removed, so you either need to run compass after, or put the compass files into the css folder in the root directory, and then jekyll will just copy the files correctly.